# what does *(flow + i*n + j) mean in C? I have no idea what this topic is called

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C and C++ Programming however I saw in my Algorithms class(I transferred from a Java oriented school to a C++ oriented curriculum) that I had no idea what this meant:

```
*(flow + i*n + j) += minFlowPath;
```

I am not sure what this pointer thing is called. I want to learn the logic of what that means and what is being stored. Thank you
Please redirect me.

Comment: First of all `*(flow + i*n + j)` means that you have missed providing declaration and definition for `flow`, `i`, `n` and `j`. Please provide some context, without that relevant information, your question too broad.

Comment: Strongly strongly STRONGLY recommend grabbing yourself [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and get familiar with C++ (not to be confused with C) or you will be totally <expletive deleted>ed when the course gets into full swing. A decent Algorithms course is hard enough. Tacking learning C++ at the same time without a good reference onto that is a good way to have to take the course twice.

Comment: If buying text books and food simultaneously is a problem, as it often is with students, here's a link to a good stop-gap since you are already familiar with programming: https://isocpp.org/tour . It's terse, but it's free.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to be sure without more context, but given the expression

```
 *(flow + i*n + j) += minFlowPath;
```

it's likely that `flow` is a pointer.  The subexpression `flow + i*n + j` constitutes *pointer arithmetic*.  Addition of a pointer and an integer yields a new pointer pointing to an element counted beyond the original pointer, so here we're pointing to the element which is `i*n + j` elements beyond wherever `flow` points.  (As Barmar points out in a comment, this suggests that `flow` is being treated as a flattened 2D array, accessing the `i,j`th element.)

Given any pointer or pointer-valued expression, the unary `*` operator access the value that the pointer points to.  So

```
 *(flow + i*n + j)
```

is the value which is `i*n + j` past whatever `flow` points to.

When you access a pointer using `*` in this way, you get something called an *lvalue*, a technical term meaning that you can do more than just fetch the pointed-to value, you can also *modify* the pointed-to value.  And that's exactly what we do here.  C's `+=` operator adds to a value, in-place.  So whatever the pointed-to value was, we add the value `minFlowPath` to it.

To learn more about this, read up on *pointer arithmetic*, *pointer indirection*, and *assignment operators*.

Comment: This is basically treating `flow` as a pointer to a 2-d array in row-major order, and incrementing `flow[i][j]`.

Comment: Yes, and that's more of a C-thing to do rather than C++. In C++, you'd probably just overload [].

Comment: More accurately, the multiplication operator `*` has highest precedence so `i` binds to `n` and `i*n` is calculated first. From thereon, the `+` operator has left-to-right associativity,  so `flow + i*n` is calculated next, the result of the expression being of same pointer type as `flow`. And then that result `+ j` is calculated, the result again being of the same pointer type. Meaning that strictly speaking `i*n + j` is never calculated. Does it matter? Well maybe, `i*n+j` could in theory give an integer overflow which won't necessarily happen with pointer arithmetic.